# Is it possible to show contents in a specific sites for multilingual site?

Tags: 7, nodes, i18n-l10n, uri, redirection

> Is it possible to show contents in a specific sites for multilingual
>   site?

I have a site of multilingual support with english and bangla language.
There is a content type blog. so Now I want to publish english content in a `en.demo.com` site and bangla content at `bn.demo.com` site and the different content will be visible at different site and it will generate different url. Is it possible and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `en/admin/config/regional/language/configure` and make sure `URL` is at the top. Press `configure` and select `Domain`. There you go.

Comment: You might want to read Gábor Hojtsy's post on [Node translations](http://hojtsy.hu/blog/2011-jan-31/drupal-7039s-new-multilingual-systems-part-4-node-translation).

Comment: It's solved. Thanks @Win Mostery for trying to help